# Where to put forever logs on OpenShift

Tags: node.js, logging, openshift, forever

[Forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) gives you the options:

```
-l  LOGFILE      Logs the forever output to LOGFILE
-o  OUTFILE      Logs stdout from child script to OUTFILE
-e  ERRFILE      Logs stderr from child script to ERRFILE
```

I want to have access to my logs for my application when I do `rhc tail`. Where do I tell forever to log my application if I want it to behave just as if I were running the process with `node server.js`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would direct them to the ~/nodejs/logs/node.log, that file gets picked up by rhc tail, and you should have write access to it.